# How to create an alias to the directories and copy one file to another?

Tags: bash, directory, alias

I want to copy a file from `/home/e_empid/file1` to `/home/e_empid /dir1/dir2/dir3/Backupfile1`.  User does not want to write a long command each time. Write a command to set an alias for above action?

I tried the below code

```
alias a= 'cd ~/e_empid/'
alias b= 'cd ~/e_empoid/dir1/dir2/dir3/'
```

I want to copy the `file1` to `backupfile1`. How should I do it after I create an alias?

Answer (score 3):

Change your aliases to variable like below without `cd` command and without space after `=` sign and remove last `/` because the aliases won't work inside `cp` command or you can use function instead; As @jherran's answer which it's more flexible with function.

```
sorc=~/e_empid
dest=~/e_empoid/dir1/dir2/dir3/Backupfile1
```

Then use that like:

```
cp $sorc/file1 $dest/
```

If you run above command, the `file1` file will be copy from `~/e_empid` directory into `~/e_empoid/dir1/dir2/dir3/Backupfile1` directory.

You can add them to end of `.bashrc` file to using for next time:

```
echo 'sorc=~/e_empid' >> .bashrc
echo 'dest=~/e_empoid/dir1/dir2/dir3/Backupfile1' >> .bashrc
```

and use `cp $sorc/Any_File_inside_it $dest/` .

Comment: it says no such file or directory

Comment: Thank you. And can u help me with how to display the welcome message every time i log into unix?

Comment: @panni Please ask that as new question. thank you. and please [read here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and don't forget accept answer.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171938/how-to-display-welcome-message-in-unix

Comment: @panni please [read here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and don't forget to mark as accept answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bash, you can create a function instead of an alias.

```
bcopy () {
    cd ~/e_empid/
    cp file1 /home/e_empid/dir1/dir2/dir3/Backupfile1
    cd ~/e_empoid/dir1/dir2/dir3/
}
```

Then you just need to call using `bcopy`.

You could also use `$1` and `$2` instead of `file1` and `Backupfile1` if your files does not have the same names every time.

```
cp $1 /home/e_empid/dir1/dir2/dir3/$2
```

In this case, you need to call using `bcopy orig-file dest-file`.